# call a method inside anouther in angular 2 service

Tags: angular

I'm getting a `Property 'getKey' does not exist on type 'HTMLAnchorElement'`error.

I've tried many solutions but I still have the same problem.
I want to extract the `text` from the `<a>` tag and use it in another method.
I need to do that so I can send that text to another service witch is `list.service1.ts`.
I'm trying to send it directly by doing: `this.listService1.findList(text);` instead of creating a middle method, but  the same error appears: `Property 'listService1' does not exist on type 'HTMLAnchorElement'`.
I need that every time I click on `<a>` tag I can use the text in it in other service method.

### list.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ListService {
    constructor(private listService1: ListService1) {
        this.listService1 = listService1;
    }

    findAllList() {
        const ulList = document.getElementById('list1');
        const dbrefList = database().ref().child('LISTE_OFFRE_EN_ATTEND');
        const dbrefList1 = dbrefList.child('LISTE_OFFRE_EMPLOI');
        dbrefList1.on('child_added', snap => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = "aff-offre";
            const list1 = snap.key;
            a.innerText = list1;
            li.appendChild(a);
            ulList.appendChild(li);
            a.addEventListener("click", function () {
                const text = a.outerText;
                this.getKey(text);
            });
        });
    }

    getKey(text) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are manipulating the DOM directly within a method of a service. This is not the Angular(2+) way of doing things. You probably better go through the Angular tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) or anything similar first to understand the pillars of the framework.

Comment: In addition to Picci's excellent suggestion, you can also find some "getting started" Angular 2+ code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted It shows how to use routing parameters to pass values every time the user clicks on an <a> link tag.

Comment: That said, your problem would be solved by using an arrow function (`() => `) rather than an anonymous `function ()`.

Comment: ok thank you so much